# Updating linestring geometry by replacing its points

Tags: postgis

I have a linestring on my postgis. and I want to update a point in this linestring. I mean I want to update the geometry of the point in the line string by an other points

Comment: Do you have a statement that you have tried?  Please edit your question to include more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @taudorf answer. Point for update is `POINT(-1 2.8)`. If you want to update the point by the closest one in a maximum distance of 1 unit you should do:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
    ST_SetPoint('LINESTRING(-1 2,-1 3)', 
        (
            SELECT path-1
            FROM (
                    SELECT (dumped).path[1], (dumped).geom
                    FROM (
                           SELECT ST_DumpPoints(lines_a.geom) dumped
                           FROM (
                                 SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-1 2,-1 3)', 3857) geom
                                ) lines_a
                 ) dumped_points
            ) dumped_points
            JOIN (
                SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-1 1.5)', 3857) geom
            ) point ON ST_DWithin(point.geom, dumped_points.geom, 1)
            ORDER BY ST_Distance(point.geom, dumped_points.geom)
            LIMIT 1
         ), 'POINT(-1 1.5)')) new_geom
```

Note that if you change both `2.8` to `1.7` the updated point will change to the first point of the line because it is closer.
If you want to change tolerance of the point distance change the `1` value from  `ST_DWithin(point.geom, dumped_points.geom, 1)`.

### NOTE

This is different from what @taudorf updated. That SQL he posted will update the point if you know the geometry of the point you want to be updated AND the point you want it to become.

With this statement you will need to know only the point you want the updated one to become. The one to update will be get by proximity.

Comment: Yep, my solution will work when the the exact point is known. @maryame said the the geometry of the point was known so I assumed that it was the exact geometry. But if that is not the case then your solution is the one to go with and it is more robust to find the nearest point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **ST_SetPoint** function to replace a point in a linestring.The example below replaces the first point in the linestring with another point given as the last parameter:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SetPoint('LINESTRING(-1 2,-1 3)', 0, 'POINT(-1 1)'));
```

You can read more about the ST_SetPoint function [here](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_SetPoint.html)

**Update:**

Since the index of the point to be replaced is not known, it is necessary to find it. You can do this with the help of ST_DumpPoints and ST_Equals. The example below uses these functions to find the index:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SetPoint('LINESTRING(-1 2,-1 3)', 
(SELECT points.point_index -1 as index FROM
(
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(line.geom)).path[1] as point_index, (ST_DumpPoints(line.geom)).geom 
FROM
(SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-1 2,-1 3)') as geom) line
)  points
WHERE ST_Equals(points.geom, 'POINT(-1 2)')), 'POINT(-1 1)'));
```

Comment: I know just the geometry of the point that I want to update but not the position

Comment: I think you'd have to dump the points from the linestring, filter the closest point and then in `path` column of the dump results you will have what is the position of the closest point. Will be a little tricky though, good luck.

Comment: @maryame, I have just updated my answer. Please incorporate your comment in the question.

Comment: I adapt your code to my case but it not works :                                                      SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SetPoint(a.geom, 
(SELECT points.point_index -1 as index FROM
(
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(line.geom)).path[1] as point_index, (ST_DumpPoints(line.geom)).geom 
FROM
(SELECT ST_GeomFromText(a.geom) as geom) line
)  points
WHERE ST_Equals(points.geom, b.geom_osm)), b.geom , b.geom )) from public."zone1" a,tableau_despoints_a_remplacer b ;

Comment: I have that in the result : parse error - invalid geometry

Comment: Thats because you had a ST_GeomFromText on your a.geom. Below is an example thats looks more like your adaption. You can replace last line starting from FROM with your line - from public."zone1" a,tableau_despoints_a_remplacer b - and give it a try.

Comment: SELECT ST_AsText(
ST_SetPoint(
 a.geom, 
  (SELECT points.point_index -1 as index FROM 
   ( SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(line.geom)).path[1] as point_index, (ST_DumpPoints(line.geom)).geom 
   FROM (
    SELECT a.geom) line 
   ) points 
   WHERE ST_Equals(points.geom, b.geom_osm)
   )
  , b.geom )) 
FROM (SELECT  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-1 2,-1 3)') as geom) a, (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-1 2)') as geom_osm, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-1 1)') as geom) b